# How to obtain INITIAL data file size in T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

By initial I mean at time of database creation.

Example:

`CREATE DATABASE foo ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'foo_Data', FILENAME = N'M:\foo_data.MDF' , SIZE = 1MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 30%), 
 FILEGROUP [INDEXES] 
( NAME = N'foo_Indexes', FILENAME = N'I:\foo_Indexes.ndf' , SIZE = 1MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 30%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'foo_log', FILENAME = N'L:\foo_Log.LDF' , SIZE = 1MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 30%)
GO`

User inserts 1.1MB of records to foo database.  File size for foo_data would now be expanded to 1.3MB and 1.3MB would be reflected in sys.master_files and sys.database_files.

Is initial size (1MB for foo_data.mdf) stored anywhere in SQL Server?

Comment: No, I don't think that value is stored anywhere - what do you need it for anyway?? It just sets the initial size of the database - once it's done, that value becomes uninteresting..

Comment: Do you want to know to see what `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` will regard as the minimum size to shrink to? I think perhaps `MinSize` in `DBCC FILEHEADER ('YourDBName')` shows this but haven't tested that idea.